# Handling CData in converting Xml to Json using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, cdata

I'm trying to convert an Xml to Json and run some business logic and then Deserialize into a c# object using **Newtonsoft Json.Net**. The Xml has CData values. How can I deserialize the Json such that I get the value inside CData mapped to a c# field.

EDIT: The xml may/maynot contain CData

E.g.
**Xml:**

With CData

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <text><![CDATA[Sample Text]]></text>
</root>`

With plain text

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <text>Sample Text></text>
</root>`

**Json:**

With CData:

`{"text":{"#cdata-section":"Sample Text"}}`

With plain text:

`{"text":"Sample Text"}`

Code:

```
class Data
{
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
}

public static Data ConvertJsonToObject(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
}
```

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

xsd for your xml sample. I defined CDATA as a simple type extending string and a complex type for the text node containing the CDATA.

```
<xs:element name="root" type="CDATA_TEXT" /> 
<xs:simpleType name="CDATA">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="CDATA_TEXT">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="text" type="CDATA" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Generated cs file from xsd:

```
namespace Q38072488.Xml
{
  using System;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;

  [Serializable()]
  [XmlRoot("root", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  public partial class CDATA_TEXT
  {
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Json classes:

```
namespace Q38072488.Json
{
  using Newtonsoft.Json;

  public class CDataText
  {
      [JsonProperty("#cdata-section")]
      public string CDATA_Section { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootObject
  {
      [JsonProperty("text")]
      public CDataText Text { get; set; }
  }
}
```

deserialize from xml and convert to json (you could add implicit conversion):

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("cdata.xml") ) {
  var srlz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xml.CDATA_TEXT));
  var xmlCdataText = (Xml.CDATA_TEXT)srlz.Deserialize(fs);
  var ro = new Json.RootObject() { 
    Text = new Json.CDataText() {
      CDATA_Section = xmlCdataText.Text } };
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Andrei for the reply. The problem here is the field may or may not contain CData. In one xml the field might have CData and in another xml the field might have plain text, the solution should work for both the cases. (I apologize I missed to mention this info in the question)